# JUnit test case failure. java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[I@12c5431> but was:<[I@14b6bed>

Tags: java

I have been facing this problem for a while and it starts frustrating me. The code needs to return the k elements of a nearest to val. This method will throw an IllegalArgumentException if k is negative and return an array of zero length if k == 0 or if k > a.length. When I run the test case against this method, it reports:

```
There was 1 failure:
1) nearestKTest(SelectorTest)
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[I@12c5431> but was:<[I@14b6bed>
       at SelectorTest.nearestKTest(SelectorTest.java:21)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

I know this means expected didn't match actual. I just could not figure it out. :(

```
public static int[] nearestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {
  int[] b = new int[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
     b[i] = Math.abs(a[i] - val);
  }
  Arrays.sort(b);      
  int[] c = new int [k];
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
     if (k < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("k is not invalid!");
     }
     else if (k == 0 || k > a.length){
     return new int[0];}
     else{
     c[i] = b[i];}   
  }
  return c;   
}


Test case:

import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class SelectorTest {


   /** Fixture initialization (common initialization
    *  for all tests). **/
   @Before public void setUp() {
   }


   /** A test that always fails. **/
   @Test public void nearestKTest() {
    int[] a = {2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 15, 32};
    int[] expected = {6, 7};
    int[] actual = Selector.nearestK(a, 6, 2);
    Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing `Object` references. Either use [`Arrays.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) to compare array content

```
Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expected, actual));
```

or the JUnit [`assertArrayEquals`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```

as suggested by @Stewart. Obviously the latter is simpler.

Comment: Thanks! But after I correct this error, it gave me error.There was 1 failure:
1) nearestKTest(SelectorTest)
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:<6> but was:<0>. I think there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: That's because `nearestK` is returning `[0, 1]` but you are expecting `[6, 7]`

Comment: You can also use `Assert.equals(Arrays.toString(expected), Arrays.toString(actual));`  I find the error message more informative.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
```