# Java JUnit test to achieve branch coverage

Tags: java

Here is the code that I need to create JUnit tests to achieve branch coverage,

```
    public String toString(int p, int q) {
        if (p > 3 && q < 25) {
            if (p > 50) {
                System.out.println("p/q=" + (p / q));
            } else {
                System.out.println("p+q=" + (p + q));
            }
            if (q < 12) {
                System.out.println("p*q=" + (p * q));
            } else {
                System.out.println("sqrt(p*q)=" + Math.sqrt(p * q));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("p-q=" + (p - q));
        }
        return toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt,

```
@Test
public void QB2test() {
    Assert.assertEquals(35, toString(15, 20));
}
```

However, it shows these actual result that I do not understand.

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>   Expected :35 
>   Actual :QB2@61e4705b

How should I modify to achieve the passed result? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are asserting the return value of the method call - toString(15, 20) with 35 and you are getting **QB2@61e4705b** as return value causing your test case to fail.

Reason is, as part of your **toString** method you are calling toString() method of Object class. toString() method of Object class always returns string representation of the current object. Here in your case it is returning object reference of your class which you are currently running.

To elaborate on this, every class in java is child of Object class either directly or indirectly. Object class contains toString() method. Whenever we try to print the Object reference then internally toString() method is invoked.
Instead of calling Object class's toString() method have a variable to store the result of your operations and return that variable value back to the caller of the method.

Please go through the below java api link to get more clarity
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--

Finally to pass your test case, change your toString(int x, int y) like below:

```
public double toString(int p, int q) {
    double result = 0;
    if (p > 3 && q < 25) {
        if (p > 50) {
            result = p / q;
            System.out.println("p/q=" + result);
        } else {
            result = p + q;
            System.out.println("p+q=" + result);
        }
        if (q < 12) {
            result = p * q;
            System.out.println("p*q=" + result);
        } else {
            result = Math.sqrt(p * q);
            System.out.println("sqrt(p*q)=" + result);
        }
    } else {
        result = p - q;
        System.out.println("p-q=" + result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Actual :QB2@61e4705b is object reference . You are comparing object refernce.
Convert object reference into value and then try it.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578071/junit-test-case-failure-java-lang-assertionerror-expectedi12c5431-but-was

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to compare a String object with an integer.